# display coordinates information on plotting graph

Tags: matlab, text, printf, coordinates

I have code `fprintf('XBBC=%6.2f,YBBC=%6.2f,XRFC=%6.2f,YRFC=%6.2f',centers1(:,1),centers1(:,2),centroids1(:,1),centroids1(:,2));`.

But when I used fprintf, it just displayed the information in the command window (XBBC=563.85,YBBC=521.51,XRFC=563.70,YRFC=522.94).

Then, what actually I want is to display "XBBC=#,YBBC=#,XRFC=#,YRFC=#" in plotted graph.

Please help me on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [text](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) to place text on a plot. For example:

```
centers1 = rand(1,2);
centroids1 = rand(1,2);

str_to_display = sprintf('XBBC=%6.2f,YBBC=%6.2f,XRFC=%6.2f,YRFC=%6.2f', ...
                            centers1(:,1), centers1(:,2), ...
                            centroids1(:,1),centroids1(:,2));



plot(rand(1,5)*5, rand(1,5)*5, '.');
xlim([0,5]); ylim([0,5]);

text(0.1,1, str_to_display)
```